# Recursion Function Isn't Working

Tags: python, string, recursion, palindrome

Okay, so I'm trying to make a recursive function that returns True if the function is a palindrome, and False otherwise. However, it doesn't go to the very end, and randomly stops.

Code:

---

```
def is_palindrome(word):

    if len(word) == 1 or len(word) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        lst = len(word) - 1
        if word[0] == word[lst]:
            print(len(word), " --> ", word)
            print(word[0], " # ", word[lst])
            is_palindrome(word[0+1:lst])
        else: 
            return False
```

---

For the life of me, I can't figure out why. Here's a sample output:

```
7  -->  racecar
r  #  r
5  -->  aceca
a  #  a
3  -->  cec
c  #  c

^ It stops right here. Why doesn't it continue and return True when length = 1?
```

Comment: `return list(word) == reversed(list(word))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to *return* your call to the recursive function:

```
def is_palindrome(word):

    if len(word) == 1 or len(word) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        lst = len(word) - 1
        if word[0] == word[lst]:
            print(len(word), " --> ", word)
            print(word[0], " # ", word[lst])
            return is_palindrome(word[0+1:lst])     # change here
        else: 
            return False
```

The reason you code appears to stop at the final step of recursion is because you never actually return a value in that case.  In some programming languages, such as C or maybe Java, such code would not even compile.  Python appears to tolerate it, though it results in your current behavior.

Comment: That makes so such sense. Thank you very much.
I'll be more careful with my recursive statements now.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

your function is too long.
I prefer to use `string[::-1]`

#

```
def is_palindrome(word):

    return word == word[::-1]
```

Comment: Haha, I'm aware of that. But I don't quite understand it, so I'm gonna avoid it. But thank you!